# В чем разница между req.grace и beresp.grace в varnish 3?

Tags: веб-программирование, proxy

Объясните разницу между этими директивами, из мануала понял что и та и та отвечают за длительность хранения объектов в кэше.
Вот в этом примере для статических данных эти директивы устанавливаются в одинаковые значения.

```
sub vcl_recv {
 set req.grace = 2m;
 if (req.url ~ "\.(png|jpe?g|gif)") {
  set req.grace = 1h;
 }
}

sub vcl_fetch {
 set beresp.grace = 1h;
}
```

И еще про директиву beresp.ttl, которая по материалам статей так же устанавливает срок хранения в кэше, расскажите, пожалуйста.
В разных статьях пишут по-разному. Например, в вот этих:

[http://ruhighload.com/index.php/2009/04/21/varnish-быстрый-старт/](http://ruhighload.com/index.php/2009/04/21/varnish-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82/)

http://webperformance.ru/2011/06/03/varnish-speed-up